# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer blinks when changing sessionPreset on a running AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I'm running a session with `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium`to process the frames, when I find what I need I want to capture a stills image with `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`. I'm changing the sessionPreset with the code

```
dispatch_async(_captureSessionQueue, ^{

        [_captureSession beginConfiguration];

        if ([_captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto])
        {
            _captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
        }

        [_captureSession commitConfiguration];
    });
```

When this code is called the screen(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) "blinks".
I can't use `highResolutionStillImageOutputEnabled` because I need to support iOS 7 and devices lower than iPhone 6. Does any one have an idea why this blink happens?

Comment: Found an answer to this?